# $R$ - commutative ring. $I$ - ideal of that ring. Prove that ring $R/I$ - is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals

$R$ - commutative ring. $I$ - ideal of that ring.  Prove that ring $R/I$ - is a field  and only if  $I$ $!=$ $R$ and any proper ideal in $R$ does not contain $I$

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: The ideal of field is only the whole field and $(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $k$ be a field. Assume $\phi\colon R\to k$ is a ring homomorphism and onto.

What can you conclude about $\ker\phi$ fomr the fact that $\phi$ is not the zero homomorphism?

What is the relation between ideals in $R$ containing $\ker\phi$ and ideals in $k$?